# Como posso fazer uma variável esperar o usuário pressionar 1 de 4 botões?

Tags: java, android, algoritmo

Bom, vou tentar ser mais claro.

Eu tenho uma variável chamada `int tentativa` e quero que ela receba um valor específico dependendo do botão que o usuário pressionar.

Os botões são `btPedra[0], btPedra[1], btPedra[2], btPedra[3]`.

Caso o usuário pressione `btPedra[0]`, a variável recebe 0.

Caso o usuário pressione `btPedra[1]`, a variável recebe 1.
E assim por diante...

Obs: O programa deve esperar o usuário pressionar um dos botões para prosseguir.

Meu código está assim:

```
for (contador = 0; contador < jogada; ++contador){

    tentativa = 
    // AQUI A VARIAVEL tentativa DEVE RECEBER 0, 1, 2 OU 3 DEPENDENDO DO BOTÃO PRESSIONADO.

    if (tentativa[contador] == sequencia[contador]){
        acertos++;
    } else {
        gameOver();
    }
}
```

Além do botão fazer com que a variável receba um valor, a cor dele será alterada.

OBS: Estou programando em java para android!

Codigo completo do metodo!

```
public void inicioJogo() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (; jogada <= 50; jogada++) {
                    for (contador = 0; contador < jogada; contador++) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(250);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                btPedra[sequencia[contador]].setBackgroundResource(imagensHover[sequencia[contador]]);
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                btPedra[sequencia[contador]].setBackgroundResource(imagensNormal[sequencia[contador]]);
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(250);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    for (contador = 0; contador < btPedra.length; ++contador){
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                btPedra[contador].setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    for (contador = 0; contador < jogada; ++contador){
                        //AQUI EU PRECISO QUE O PROGRAMA PARE E ESPERE O USUARIO PRESSIONAR UM DOS BOTÕES E DEPENDENDO DO BOTAO PRESSIONADO A VARIAVEL tentativa RECEBA DETERMINADO VALOR!
                        if (tentativa == sequencia[contador]){
                            acertos++;
                        } else {
                            gameOver();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: Por que você não joga seu último `for` pra fora da Thread e quando ele acertar tu chama a Thread novamente? Pra interromper a Thread da uma olhada [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java)

Answer (score 5):

Acredito que você colocou o mesmo `onClick` em todos né?

Uma saída é você comparar pelo `id` do componente que enviar a "clicada", assim:

```
public void cliqueGenerico(View v) {
    int tentativa;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.botaoUm:
            tentativa = 0;
            break;
        case R.id.botaoDois:
            tentativa = 1;
            break;
        case R.id.botaoTres:
            tentativa = 2;
            break;
        case R.id.botaoQuatro:
            tentativa = 3;
            break;
    }

    /* ... seu código restante */
}
```

Comment: Parece ser isso mas ainda não consegui resolver meu problema, pois quero que em um momento do looping ele espere o usuario clicar em um dos quatro botões para então prosseguir ... Não sei como aplicar ao meu looping ;/

Comment: @MichaelMarcel Poste o restante do seu código, posso te ajudar numa saída

Comment: pronto coloquei o codigo do metodo todo.

Answer (score -3):

Caso I: apenas coloque a variável "tentativa" para receber o valor do teclado. O laço irá esperar pela atribuição.

Ex por Linguagem:

Linguagem C

scanf("%d", &tentativa);

Linguagem Java

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
tentativa = scan.nextLine();

Assim o laço irá executar enquanto não for atribuído o valor 4 a variável tentativa.

Caso 2:

do {

}while(tentativa != 4);

Comment: a sua resposta é `C` ou `java` ?

Comment: Nas duas linguagens, é que na hora de postar a resposta ficou tudo junto, mas agora separei, só conferir.